# Get friendly description from a object member in C#

Tags: c#, objectbrowser

How do i get the description from a object member programmaticly?

If i use the built in Object Browser in Visual Studio i can browse a specific object and get a human redable description for every object. For example browsing **{} System.Text.RegularExpressions** and choosing the "Match(string)" member would give me the following description in the lower right pane of the Object Browser:

*public System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match Match(string input)
    Member of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex*

***Summary:**

Searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the regular expression specified in the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex constructor.


**Parameters:**

input: The string to search for a match.


**Returns:**

An object that contains information about the match.
Exceptions:
System.ArgumentNullException: input is null.*

How can i get a Console application in C# to output the same information? I have tried with both reflections and enums but have not manage to work it out. I have search in the matter but since I don't know what i should be searching for i have found nothing to point me in the right direction.

Thanks
Wylon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need the generated XML file for that, and look up your information in that. The comment data does not get embedded into compiled assemblies.

Comment: You could also use Reflection and check for the Description attribute for UI components.

Comment: @Roy: So there is no way i can generate that information manually? Im really only intrested in the first line so i can output which arguments the specific member need.

Comment: @CodingBarfield: Do you have any example or link that shows how it can be done?

Comment: @Wylon here you go:
var t = inputObject.GetType()
var descriptions = (DescriptionAttribute[])
            type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
(don't forget to upvote ;)

Comment: GetType() only gives the base object, but I got the idea! After adding .GetMethod("Match") it worked! Thanks alot!

Comment: Sorry cant seem upvote, im to fresh on the site.. :( The code i ended up using is the following though. var t = inputObject.GetType().GetMethod("<Method>"); DescriptionAttribute[] descriptions = (DescriptionAttribute[]) t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

                if (descriptions.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine (descriptions[0].Description);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine (t.ToString());
                }